# Direct access call for a twig template from a twig template gives 404

Tags: routing

I'm trying to call for a Twig template `_template` from a Twig template, particularly from within AngularJS `<script type="text/javascript"></scirpt>` tags. A console log says, that the file was not found on the server with status of 404. Using `{% include '' %}` or `{% embed '' %}`interferes with AngularJS somehow. Does any way around exists to access that Twig template, without breaching the security?

Troubleshooting part of js:

```
$mdDialog.show({
  templateUrl: '_template',
})
```

Comment: Can you give me a general idea of what's hanging out in the file.twig? Also- what issues is it giving you with the include/embed tags?

Comment: The console log says that an error is coming from angularjs. The file.twig has entries and some math to get a reviews and ratings work. It's working fine without including template path within script tags. So I thought maybe to hardcode the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you trying to do here?  Call a Twig template from Angular?

Twig is a server side technology, Angular is getting parsed on the client side. The only way Craft is going to parse a Twig template is when it encounters a URL.

Instead of calling the Twig template directly, you call the URL, which [could match a template](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing). Inside `templates`, make a folder like `angular-views` and then inside that put a file called `md-dialog.twig`.  From the front end, now you can call it from Angular like `http://example.com/angular-views/md-dialog` (the .twig is optional).

If you're trying to use Angular inside of a Twig template, you may want to use something like [`{% verbatim %}`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/verbatim.html) and then put your JS/Angular templating between those tags to make sure Twig doesn't touch any of it.

Comment: I wanted to call a Twig template from a Twig template from within `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags. So I built the path to a file, which was in a folder  with underscore("_"). That was my mistake, as It didn't occur me right away, that folders/files are hidden from direct access with underscore at the beginning.  So It was throwing me a status of `404`. Than I tried Twig's tags `{% included %}`,`{% embed %}` and `{% verbatim %}` which gave me an AngularJS error. Glad you turned in on me with your answer.

Comment: Good deal - glad it was helpful!